# Chrome: HTML date input produces strange comma

Tags: html, date, google-chrome, formatting

Whenever I use "**input with type="date"**" in Chrome, there is a strange comma on the left of the date input.
There is no such comma in Firefox and I cannot find any information regarding this.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can get rid of the comma or why it is there?
The value of the input is correct (no comma).
I only want to use the date input.

Comment: Please can you share a code example? Along with the input value you're using too please.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester It's really just an `<input type="date"/>`. The comma is there with and without a value, so the problem is independent of the value. I just realized that the problem occurs on my laptop, but not on my desktop pc. Does someone have an idea why the comma is device specific?

Comment: @tverdo Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing on my ThinkPad laptop too. (Chrome and Edge)

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be related to how Google Chrome complies with region settings in Windows.  Verify that your region settings have not been customized to display (for example) something like 'ddd, M/d/yyyy'

- Open Control Panel
- Click on Clock & Region
- Click 'Region: Change date, time, or number formats'